# Spring MVC request mapping accept multi level request

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

i have a mapping like

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login.ajx",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

which accept only `http://localhost:8080/MySite/login.ajx`

How can i make it accept

`http://localhost:8080/MySite/a/login.ajx`
or
`http://localhost:8080/MySite/a/b/login.ajx`
or
`http://localhost:8080/MySite/a/b/c/login.ajx`

so that it accept login request from any page.

**OR**

Can i re-write this

```
 $.ajax({
    url:'login.ajx',
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "text",
   ........
```

so that it will send `http://localhost:8080/MySite/login.ajx` request from any level.
(This javascript an external script that's why i cant use `${pageContext.request.contextPath}`)

Any Suggestion will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with double Asterix pattern:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/**/login.ajx",method=RequestMethod.GET)
```